# How to write mongoDb query for Objects with an array of objects

Tags: database, mongodb, backend

Remove an object, from an object with and array of objects

```
  {
    Id: 1,
    Car: {
      CarTypes: [
        {type: "chevrolet", color: "blue"},
        {type: "nissan", color: "blue"},
        {type: "hyundai", color: "blue"}
      ],
      Locked: true
    }
  }
```

I have a object with an array of objects, and i would like to remove them if the type is nissan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$filter` inside update pipeline for this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "Car.CarTypes": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$Car.CarTypes",
          cond: {$ne: ["$$this.type", "nissan"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-LETMKvhb6R)